# Returning back to MainActivity without starting a new instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

Hello I am fairly new to Andriod. I have three activities A B C. A is the MainActivity B and C are independent activities. I have included a calendar in the mainActivity and have highlighted some dates.

Now through mainActivity I start a new activity B and return back to A using the following code

```
public void OnClick(View V){
      Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),A.class);
      i.setFlags(Imtent.FLAG_ACTVITIY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(i);       
  }
```

This returns back to the mainActivity but the Highlighted dates are not there. I want to know whether the creates a fresh new Activity or I have done something wrong in highlighting the days.

Comment: What happens when you press back button? If MainActivity is your starting activity, then the app should exit.

Comment: 1. Use back or home button is enough to return to MainActivity. 2. Research about activity's launchMode.

Comment: don't start the mainActivity again, check out the BackStack. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: you need to start new activity without finishing the previous activity.. and on returning just use activityname.this.finish(); and every thing will work as you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the following row in your manifest to MainActivity:

```
...
android:launchMode="singleTask"
...
```

For example:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: No need for this. You can just call this.finish()

Comment: In some cases this.finish() is not a good solution, for example if he need back stack history. If he is in activity C and have condition to go to activity A or back to activity B without recreate the activities, then if the activity B is finished this is impossible.

Comment: Totally agree with you, but it seems that he does not require that at the moment. I might be wrong, but that's how I understood the question

Comment: No problem I just noticed.

Comment: I am in the situation Ivan had described. And I tried with finish() which closes the current activity and previous activity gets initialized.

Comment: I'm glad for that. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to start the previous activity again. You can just call `this.finish()` whenever you want to close the current activity and return to the previous one. If this is the last activity in the BackStack, the app will close.